# wp_remote_request getting alsways 403 Error

Tags: wordpress, xmlhttprequest

im trying to get the xml but i always get a 403 error. But with postman its working fine.

i dont think i did something wrong with the authorization but maybe im wrong.

this code is in the functions.php and im calling it with https://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=nopriv_search_mobileads

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_mobileads', 'get_mobileads_from_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_search_mobileads', 'get_mobileads_from_api');
function get_mobileads_from_api() {
    $url = ('https://services.mobile.de/search-api/search?');
    
    $wp_request_headers = array(
        'Host'  => 'https://services.mobile.de',
        'Accept' => 'application/xml',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode('id:pw')
    );


    $results = wp_remote_request(
        $url,
        array(
            'method'    => 'GET',
            'headers'   => $wp_request_headers
        )
    );
   print_r($results);
}
```

output:

```
Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( ) ) [body] => [response] => Array ( [code] => 403 [message] => Forbidden ) [cookies] => Array ( ) [filename] => [http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object ( [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object ( [body] => [raw] => HTTP/1.1 403 [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( ) ) [status_code] => 403 [protocol_version] => 1.1 [success] => [redirects] => 0 [url] => https://services.mobile.de/search-api/search? [history] => Array ( ) [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object ( [cookies:protected] => Array ( ) ) ) [filename:protected] => [data] => [headers] => [status] => ) ) 0
```

Comment: You aren’t passing any arguments in the URL, have they been removed for demo purposes here? Also, try removing the `host` header

Comment: there was only a page number the same URL with the same login is working in postman, thats why im confused

Answer (score 0):

Unless the actual username is "id" and the actual password is "pw" that's not going to work.

Comment: i just changed it so i dont leak it

Answer (score 0):

found a way.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ads_from_api','get_ads_from_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ads_from_api','get_ads_from_api');
function get_ads_from_api(){
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://services.mobile.de/search-api/search?',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Basic ***'
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}
```